# The code is not outputting anything ever since I added the super keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, super, superclass

Using the inheritance concept, I have common variables between the truck and car class such as no of cylinders and colour, on top of that, the truck class has a variable for towing capacity and the car class has a variable for number of seats. Therefore, I decided to use the keyword super to refer to the parent class but there seems to be no output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Vehicle {
    String color;
    int noOfCylinders;
    public Vehicle(String color, int noOfCylinders) {
        this.color = "Black";
        this.noOfCylinders = 0;
    }
    public void setColor(String c) {
        color = c;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setNoOfCylinders(int noOfCyl) {
        noOfCylinders = noOfCyl;
    }
    public int getNoOfCylinders() {
        return noOfCylinders;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String information;
        information = "is " + color + " and it has " + noOfCylinders + " cylinders";
        return information;
    }
}
public class CreateVehicle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Car CarObject = new Car(s.nextLine(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
        Truck TruckObject = new Truck(s.nextLine(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Enter the color of the car: ");
        CarObject.setColor(s.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the number of cylinders in the car: ");
        CarObject.setNoOfCylinders(s.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the number of seats in the car: ");
        CarObject.setNoOfSeats(s.nextInt());
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nEnter the color of the truck: ");
        TruckObject.setColor(s.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the number of cylinders in the truck: ");
        TruckObject.setNoOfCylinders(s.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the towing capacity of the truck (lbs): ");
        TruckObject.setTowingCapacity(s.nextInt());
        System.out.print(("\nThe car ") + CarObject.toString() + ". ");
        System.out.print(("\nThe truck ") + TruckObject.toString()+ ". ");  
    }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int noOfSeats;
    public Car(String color, int noOfCylinders, int seatNum) {
        super(color, noOfCylinders);
        this.noOfSeats = seatNum;
    }
    public void setNoOfSeats(int noOfSeat) {
        noOfSeats = noOfSeat;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.print("The car has " + noOfSeats + " seats."); 

        return super.toString();
    }   
}
class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private int towingCapacity;
    public Truck(String color, int noOfCylinders, int capacityTowing) {
        super(color, noOfCylinders);
        this.towingCapacity = capacityTowing;
    }

    public void setTowingCapacity(int towingCapacityTruck) {
        towingCapacity = towingCapacityTruck;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.print ("The truck has a towing capacity of " + towingCapacity + " lbs."); 
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

*

Comment: Why are you printing in your toString methods?

Comment: `return super.toString();` **don't** do that.

Comment: How do I override it in the subclass because both of them need to have their own overridden method for their individual variables. Towing capacity for the truck and number of seats for the car. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: `return new StringBuilder(super.toString()).append(" towing capacity=").append(towingCapacity).toString();` for example. The problem with returning `super.toString()` is that it ignores all local fields and just does what you told it (invoke and return the parent's `toString()`).

Comment: Apart from what @ElliottFrisch said, you method (which, by its name, suggests pureness) suddenly has an unexpected side effect (the printing to a `Stream`).

Comment: You might also take a look at [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) from Apache commons lang.

Comment: The return statement you suggested also does not fix the problem, there is still no output @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

```
    package problems;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateVehicle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Car CarObject = new Car(s.next(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
        Truck TruckObject = new Truck(s.next(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Enter the color of the car: ");
        CarObject.setColor(s.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the number of cylinders in the car: ");
        CarObject.setNoOfCylinders(s.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the number of seats in the car: ");
        CarObject.setNoOfSeats(s.nextInt());
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nEnter the color of the truck: ");
        TruckObject.setColor(s.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the number of cylinders in the truck: ");
        TruckObject.setNoOfCylinders(s.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the towing capacity of the truck (lbs): ");
        TruckObject.setTowingCapacity(s.nextInt());
        System.out.print(("\nThe car ") + CarObject.toString() + ". ");
        System.out.print(("\nThe truck ") + TruckObject.toString() + ". ");
    }
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private int towingCapacity;
    public Truck(String color, int noOfCylinders, int capacityTowing) {
        super(color, noOfCylinders);
        this.towingCapacity = capacityTowing;
    }

    public void setTowingCapacity(int towingCapacityTruck) {
        towingCapacity = towingCapacityTruck;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.print ("The truck has a towing capacity of " + towingCapacity + " lbs."); 
        return super.toString();
    }
}


class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int noOfSeats;
    public Car(String color, int noOfCylinders, int seatNum) {
        super(color, noOfCylinders);
        this.noOfSeats = seatNum;
    }
    public void setNoOfSeats(int noOfSeat) {
        noOfSeats = noOfSeat;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.print("The car has " + noOfSeats + " seats."); 

        return super.toString();
    }   
}

class Vehicle {
    String color;
    int noOfCylinders;
    public Vehicle(String color, int noOfCylinders) {
        this.color = "Black";
        this.noOfCylinders = 0;
    }
    public void setColor(String c) {
        color = c;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setNoOfCylinders(int noOfCyl) {
        noOfCylinders = noOfCyl;
    }
    public int getNoOfCylinders() {
        return noOfCylinders;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String information;
        information = "is " + color + " and it has " + noOfCylinders + " cylinders";
        return information;
    }
}
```

I have just changed nextLine to next, assuming you are just expecting one word as input which is a color string. And it worked.

Comment: This also does not return any output on my IDE (JDoodle or Eclipse) @yogesh Kanwate

Comment: *This also does not return any output on my IDE (JDoodle or Eclipse)* Today is a **great** day to learn about [Launching and Debugging a Java program](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php) (in eclipse).

Comment: @HetParikh are you giving proper inputs in the console? Because after every string and integer you type you should click enter.